python requestでPOSTした後にtableを取得しようとするとraise ValueError("No tables found")　ValueError: No tables foundが出る
iataの航空サイトからコードを調べるプログラムを本から修正しつつ作成しているのですが
tableを取得するところでエラーになります。どう修正すればよいでしょうか？
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests.sessions
import pandas
import io
import time

url = "https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search"


def get_results(airline_name):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(
        {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36"
        }
    )

    r = session.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    form = html_soup.find("div", {"class": "row"})
    data = {}
    for inp in form.find_all(["input"]):
        name = inp.get("name")
        value = inp.get("value")
        if not name:
            continue
        if "airline.search" in name:
            value = airline_name
        if "airport.search" in name:
            value = ""
        data[name] = value if value else ""

    r = session.post(url, data=data)
    time.sleep(3)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    table = html_soup.find("table", {"class": "datatable"})
    df = pandas.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table)))
    return df


df = get_results("Lufthansa")
print(df)


言葉足らずですみません。404NotFoundではなく、raise ValueError("No tables found")　ValueError: No tables found　というエラーです。inputは取得できています

すみません　修正しました

この辺の記事等で代替出来るものもあるのでは？ SIS Member List, List of level 2 & 3 Airports, List of airline codes, ...A～...Z, ip2location-iata-icao

あるいは書籍の内容を基に作業しているのなら、その書籍名と元となったプログラムは何処に記載されているどのようなものか、といった情報を追記してみると良いかもしれません。

そのIATAのページのソースを確認するか、あるいは実際に使ってみてください。現在はPOSTではなくGETになっていることが分かります。
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import io

url = "https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search"


def get_results(airline_name):
    r = requests.get(url, params={"airline.search": airline_name})
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    table = html_soup.find("table", {"class": "datatable"})
    df = pandas.read_html(io.StringIO(str(table)))
    return df


df = get_results("Lufthansa")
print(df)

[            Company name Country / Territory 2-letter code
0  Deutsche Lufthansa AG             Germany            LH]


ありがとうございます！ご指摘の通り、ページを確認したところgetになっておりました。また綺麗なコードを書いていただきとても参考になりました。ありがとうございました。
